# PHP if post is already displayed, then

Tags: loop

I have created a new page with a jquery carousel which rotates between various different news topics. You can see [here](http://www.touringcars.net/test1.php):

However below the carousel is a static list of additional headlines. What I need to do is find php code that says IF a story appears in the carousel, THEN exclude it from the posts below. This is to avoid duplication.

I cannot simply increase the offset. The offset is currently set to '4'. The carousel contains 12 unique posts at any given time. I cannot increase the offset because if I get five or six posts in a row from one category, then they would be missed from the section below by increasing the offset.

I hope this makes sense. I'm not even sure my goal is attainable(!). Does this all need to be done within the one loop?

The carousel is a loop - it works with the following code:

```
<?php query_posts("showposts=1&offset=0&cat=$panel"); ?>
```

where

```
<div id="panel<?php print $panelCount; ?>" class="panel">
```

from

```
<?php 
$panelArray = array('131','129,131,313,318','129','318'); 
$panelCount = 0; 
foreach( $panelArray as &$panel ) { 
    $panelCount = $panelCount + 1;
}
?>
```

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: Please modify your carousel to use a proper `new WP_Query()`, rather than `query_posts()`, and then we should be able to help provide a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Track the IDs, and "exclude" them with `post__not_in`. It is hard to tell exactly what does what with the disjointed way you posted your code but the general case solution is ..

```
$c_posts = new WP_Query("showposts=10");
$tracker = array();
if ($c_posts->have_posts()) {
  while ($c_posts->have_posts()) {
   $c_posts->the_post();
   $tracker[] = get_the_ID();
   // more code
  }
}
$other_loop = new WP_Query(array('post__not_in' => $tracker));
```

Depending on how much control you have over things, there are other ways to do it. For example,if you need 5 posts in the carousel and 10 in the body you could pull all 15 at once, use the first five in the carousel and the use up the rest later, thus saving yourself a query.

### Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 1):

If your slider shows posts in a particular category, which is defined by the variable `$panel`, then you can cleanly separate the slider posts from the normal flow.

### Display Slider

Use `new WP_Query()` in your template to output the slider:

```
$slider = new WP_Query( array(
    // 'showposts' is deprecated; use 'posts_per_page'
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    // For an integer; 
    // if $panel is a string (category slug), use 'category_name'
    'cat' => $panel 
) );

if ( $slider->have_posts() ) : while ( $slider->have_posts() ) : $slider->the_post();
    // Slider loop/markup here
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_postdata();

// Normal loop here
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // Normal loop markup
endwhile; endif;
```

### Filter the main loop query

Add a filter callback to `functions.php` to filter the slider posts:

```
function wpse99748_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_singular() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $panel = array(); // Need to use ID here
        $query->set( 'category__not_in', $panel );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse99748_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chip. It may take me a little while to see if this works.

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by 'Need to use ID here'?

Comment: The `category__not_in` parameter requires an array of Post **IDs**.

Comment: I am not looking to exclude any categories from the slider at the top, though. All posts need to pass through the category into the content below it. So all categories are eligible for all locations. I need to be able to prevent duplication of posts in the carousel from the area beneath.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the array of post IDs - I can't reference them explicitly because the post IDs are constantly changing... ?

Comment: How are you going to differentiate/identify the posts in the slider?

Comment: If I could use php to say ignore the latest FOUR posts from EITHER category 129, 131, 313 or 318. But without referencing specific posts IDs (because the posts in the slider are constantly changing and my code in the slider isn't).

It can't be as simple as excluding the last four posts from category 129, the last four from 131 etc. either. It needs to be the last four from either of those.

I hope that makes sense...

Comment: Actually that didn't make sense, as an offset on those categories would do that. Let me sleep on it...

Comment: Let me rephrase the question: how is *the user* going to determine which posts to include in the slider?